# Python: import issue

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to run my code in Eclipse using PyDev.  I've successfully imported:

```
import socket
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
import time
import random
import glob
import os
import sys
import math
from pygooglechart import SimpleLineChart
```

but the below import fails (Unresolved import):

```
import settings
```

For reference, settings is used as follows:

```
    # Make a chart
    chart = SimpleLineChart(settings.width, settings.height, y_range=(0, max(rateSizeArray)))
    chart.add_data(rateSizeArray)
    chart.download('send-rates.png')
```

Examples that I've seen do exactly as I have here and there are no import errors. I have absolutely no idea as to how I to resolve this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to create a file named settings.py and put width and height values in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`settings` sounds like it's your own code - do you have an `__init__.py` in the directory you're trying to import from? (Python will typically refuse to import from directories that lack an `__init__.py` file, unless it's the same directory the python interpreter was initially invoked in.)